# I'm trying to upgrade Android old library to androidx (Android + Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

but when I build it gives me an error
recently android updated for kotlin

and my android gradle vesion is 3.1.2
and kotlin version is 1.2.41
android studio 3.1.2
i'm targeting android p
this is latest version so i can't find more documentation on this problem and

please help me to find out this problem
`android issues`

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$StubApi21
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

    //firebase massaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0-alpha1"
    def room_version = "2.0.0-alpha1"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"

    // room database persistent
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"

    //data binding
    //kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

please help me what is problem I can't find out

Comment: I think I have to wait for android stable channel and android jetpack production

Comment: i'm afraid what should i do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i removed Androidx from my whole project but isue still parsist then 
i found solution and replace

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha1'`

to

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:0.3'`
and my problem is solved.
anyway thanks all second-time I'm going to use androidx (Android + Kotlin)

I'm waiting for jetpack stable version.

Comment: not working back to app.support, still bugging androidx

Answer (score 0):

have you tried downloading android studio 3.2 canary 14? there is a  new option to convert your files to androidX and will give you a preview of what it's going to do. Back up your files or at least use git to make sure it's safe.

thanks for the edit paul

Comment: I think androidx is not compatible I should return to normal

Comment: You mean 3.2? https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/05/android-studio-32-canary-14-now.html

Comment: is there any way to rollback refactor androidx. ??

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a bug in Canary 14. You should wait for Canary 15 ;-)

Check out [this](https://youtu.be/jdKUm8tGogw?t=15m10s) session.